# How to label a list by its numbers position in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, data

Doing something like

```
Show[ListPlot[{1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10}], 
 ListLinePlot[{1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10}]]
```

I would know how to index each element in the ListPlot like the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try:

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[
  Callout[#1, First[#2], Above] &, {1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]